# A TypeVar for a function argument which is Optional?

Tags: python, pytorch, type-hinting, python-3.10

I have a base class to specify the input and output of a function.:

```py
import typing as ty
import abc
import typing_extensions as te

In = ty.TypeVarTuple("In")
Out = ty.TypeVar("Out")

# Base is actually from a library. And it has no type hints.
class Base:
    def inner_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do various operations along with calling `inner_function`
        out = self.inner_function(*args, **kwargs)
        # do more stuff
        return out

# This class is just for type hinting.
class TypeHintedBase(Base, ty.Generic[te.Unpack[In], Out]):
    
    def function(self, *args: te.Unpack[In]) -> Out:
        return super().function(*args)
```

I used `TypeVarTuple` because `function` may receive multiple inputs.

The problem occurred when I tried to give an optional argument.

```py
class Subclass(TypeHintedBase[int, int | None, int]):
    def inner_function(self, a: int, b: int | None = None) -> int:
        ...

Subclass().function(1) # <- Type checker (pylance) complains here
```

In the last line, my type checker complains that it requires another positional argument. I think it's because the type-hinting on the class definition has no default value.

But I can't think of a way to type hint that it has a default value.

In essence I want to do something like:

```
class Subclass(typeHintedBase[int, int | None = None, int]):
    pass
```

Is there a method for solving this problem?

python version: 3.10.12

Additional context: This happened during implementation of an artificial neural network using `pytorch`. Where `function` is `torch.nn.Module.__call__` and `inner_function` is `torch.nn.Module.forward`.

Comment: I just added `Subclass.function` with type hints.